# Copy files with certain extension php4

Tags: php, copy

I am writing a small script to copy files with a certain extension in a directory to another directory. 
At the moment I have:

```
<?php

$targetDir = "D:\\test dir\\";

$files = glob("C:\\old dir\\*.txt");

foreach ($files as $tocopy) {
    copy($tocopy, $targetDir);
}

?>
```

However this does not seem work. I can print_r the files and it finds them, but does not copy over.
How can I copy over files with.txt extension into a different directory?

Comment: You need to add the filename to the target too.

Comment: as Ben said, add the filename `copy($tocopy, $targetDir . $tocopy);`

Comment: Same result. I can print_r the results and it picks up two .txt files. When it comes to the copy bit, it doesn't actually copy the files over :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used xcopy inside "system" php tags to copy instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the filename to the target too. Something similar to the following should help.

```
$targetDir = "D:\\test dir\\";

$files = glob("C:\\old dir\\*.txt");

foreach ($files as $file) {
    copy($file, $targetDir . $file);
}
```

Comment: Same result. I can print_r the results and it picks up two .txt files. When it comes to the copy bit, it doesn't actually copy the files over :(